# autofill functionality for website who source code cannot be altered

Tags: javascript, java, web, autofill

I have a website whose source code cannot be changed.It has several forms which has repetative fields so for reducing manual fiiling of repeatative fields i want autofill functionality.I will have another website from where data will be stored and this data is used to fill form on first website. can anyone please suggest the possible ways.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about this issue? What can you do? redirect to a proxy? Use Javascript? Cookies? Plugin on browser?

Comment: What I want is to cache the data from first form on one website designed by me and to auto fill that data to another identical form on another website . Please give me a possible hint to accomplish the same. @RoyFalk

Answer (score 0):

First, here's what I don't think can work. If you only change the code to your site and browse to the other site, there's no way I know to auto fill and I doubt there is because it would be a security hole. If you can write, you can usually read...

There are two ways I can see this done and both have potential legal issues.

1. Make a Chrome plugin (or Firefox if you want less market share). Plugins can auto fill sites. For example [this one](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTzcS5ydvMAhUDWCwKHTEWBdAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fautofill%2Fnlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNEA3kY2uFqLj5u-rynZM_Q30wAjmw&sig2=SDXWVbHBW9s8rfCUw5GHWQ&bvm=bv.122129774,d.bGg). You didn't specify whether this is just for you or for a group of people. Distributing plugins like this can be harder if you have to go through the Chrome extension store vetting.
2. Make your website a proxy of the other site. Easier if the other site has API for partners or mobile apps. Your site would browse to the other site and fill out the form.

I'll repeat and expand on my warning. Site owners frown upon such behavior. Loss of ad revenue; legal exposure; security issues. Depending on where you're operating and the site in question, this could be considered 'hacking'.

Comment: nothing here is like 'hacking'. Actually I want to do some automation in my business so as to reduce the manual effort and time as well. I was going through the HTMLUNIT api of java that I believe allows to access the form of any website and fill it. So a logic could be built that takes data from first form and fills it to another. I am not sure but this might help

Comment: If it helps, please upvote. If it solves, please mark it as 'accepted'. If your solution is the solution, after a day or two you can add it and then accept it.